The map lags when updating the marker position in flutter_map
Tell me, here in flutter_map I have points that update their position every second, let's say, through Consumer I track the change of this point, the problem is that when a point changes its position on the map, the entire screen freezes, the world is like this, while it is every time the point is updated and redrawn on the map. What could be the reason for this and how can it be fixed?
Here is my code
Consumer<MapModel>(builder: (context, mapModel, child) {
          return PolylineLayer(
            polylines: [
              Polyline(
                points: waypoints.map((e) => e.point).toList(),
                strokeWidth: 4,
                color: AppColors.purple500,
              ),
              Polyline(
                points: waypoints.isEmpty
                    ? []
                    : [mapModel.mapPoints[0], waypoints[0].point],
                strokeWidth: 4,
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(198, 252, 172, 1),
                isDotted: true,
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
        Consumer<MapModel>(builder: (context, mapModel, child) {
          return MarkerLayer(
            markers: [
              ...waypoints.map((e) => e.marker),
              Marker(
                point: mapModel.mapPoints[0],
                child: SvgPicture.asset(AppIcons.dronePositionSvg),
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              )
            ],
          );
        }),

